# How can I check which widget was clicked?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I need to show different data when the different widget will be clicked. For example widget one will show me activity with number 1 and widget to with numer 2 :)

Perhaps I can send some data by intent from widget, but then how to recive that data in activity class? 
Widget class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Information.class);
        intent.putExtra("widget_id", appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget1x1);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_layout, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bundle extras = intent.getBundle();
String id = extras.getString("widget_id");
```

Comment: `intent.putExtra("widget_id", appWidgetId);` is in widget class, and your code should be in activity so how can I bound it?

Comment: After intent.putExtra you will invoke activity by passing intent as parameter, isn't it?

Comment: um, yes + pendingintent bacause it's a widget

Comment: because you add id as extra to intent, it will be passed. Try and see.

Comment: ... i dont know how to do it, force close or there is any value. `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  int id = extras.getInt("widget_id");`  << activity | widget code is in 1. post